# Can't validate email with Vuelidate in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm trying to use validation option in a form. The app is developing under Vue3.
I have installed *npm install @vuelidate/core @vuelidate/validator* into project folder. In a file main.js I have been trying to add Vuelidate as following:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min'
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(Vuelidate).mount('#app')
```

Next I am working on Login.vue file as following

```
<template>
    <form class="card auth-card" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Example</span>
        <div class="input-field">
        <input
            id="email"
            type="text"
            v-model.trim="email"
            :class="{invalid: ($v.email.$dirty && !$v.email.required) || ($v.email.$dirty && !$v.email.email)}"
        >
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <small class="helper-text invalid"
        v-if="$v.email.$dirty && !$v.email.required"
        >Could not be empty</small>
        <small class="helper-text invalid"
        v-else-if="$v.email.$dirty && !$v.email.email"
        >Incorrect form</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
        <div>
        <button
            class="btn waves-effect waves-light auth-submit"
            type="submit">
             Enter-login
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import { email, required, minLength } from '@vuelidate/validators'
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'

export default {
  name: 'login',
  setup () {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() }
  },
  data: () => ({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }),
  validations: {
    email: { email, required },
    password: { required, minLength: minLength(6) } 
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit () {
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.$v.$touch()
        return
      }
      this.$router.push('/') 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then I try to run all that with npm run serve but with no success. Chrome DeveloperTools inform me about "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'super' of undefined*".

What did I do wrong? Is it possible to use Vue3 and Vuelidate together?

Lidia

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title just repeats the information already available in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Step 1:* Import `useVuelidate` inside component

```
import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
import { email, required, minLength } from "@vuelidate/validators";
```

*Step 2:* Initalize `useVuelidate` inside component

```
setup() {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() };
},
```

*Step 3:* Initalize your `modal` data

```
data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
},
```

*Step 4:* Add `validations` rule

```
validations() {
    return {
      email: { email, required },
      password: { required, minLength: minLength(6) }
    };
},
```

*Step 5:* Add form `submit` method

```
methods: {
  onSubmit: function() {
    this.v$.$touch();
    if (this.v$.$error) return;
    alert('Form is valid')
  }
}
```

*Step 6:* HTML `template` design will be like,

```
<form class="card auth-card" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">Example</span>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input id="email" type="text" v-model.trim="email">
        <small class="error" v-for="(error, index) of v$.email.$errors" :key="index">
          {{ capitalizeFirstLetter(error.$property) }} {{error.$message}}
        </small>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="email">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input id="email" type="text" v-model.trim="password">
        <small class="error" v-for="(error, index) of v$.password.$errors" :key="index">
          {{ capitalizeFirstLetter(error.$property) }} {{error.$message}}
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <div>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light auth-submit" type="submit"> Enter-login<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-davinci-hvmih)

Comment: @Lidia Hope it helps you! Please let me know if need more details.

Comment: @Jebasuthen, thank you very much! It works for me (after updating labels for password).

Comment: @Lidia Its my pleasure. If my solutions works for you give then kindly accept the answer and give a thumbs up!.

Comment: don't use data() since this is vue3

Comment: @ShinyaKoizumi vue3 still uses data().