# How to configure correctly vuelidate?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Using the latest version of Vue

I've been trying to make Vuelidate work

Every guide I see on the internet using this type of "Main.js" code:
import Vue from 'vue';

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';

import App from './app/App';

Vue.use(Vuelidate);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

While my main.js looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'


createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Trying to use in my component as followed:

```
 import { required, email } from '@vuelidate/validators'
  import {useVuelidate} from "@vuelidate/core";

    export default {
data: () => ({
    v$: useVuelidate(),
```

Trying to implement it like this:

```
<div v-if="submitted && !$v.validations.affiliate.required"></div>
```

Getting this error:
unable to resolve type of v$

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

createApp(App).use(Vuelidate).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Unfotunentlymy component disappeared, i see only blank page

Comment: I see error also in import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'(error in typo)

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using? This works with Vue 3.

Comment: "vue": "^3.0.0",

Comment: @OsherRevach checkout vue3 Vuelidate with demo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945380/cant-validate-email-with-vuelidate-in-vue3/67024464#67024464

Comment: @Jebasuthan, How can I implement your guide on a staged form?